# A surjecive homomorphism of $ \mathbb R $-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

### The main question

Let $ A $ and $ B $ be two algebras over the real numbers, and let $ J $ be an ideal of $ B $. Let $ f\colon A\to B $ be a homomorphism of $ \mathbb R $-algebras, and suppose $ f^{-1}(J)\subset \ker q \circ f $, where $ q $ is the canonical projection $ q\colon B\twoheadrightarrow B/J $.

Then there exists a unique (injective) homomorphism $ \tilde f $ making the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>p>> A/f^{-1}(J)\\
@VfVV @VV{\tilde f}V\\
B @>q>> B/J
\end{CD}
$$
commute. Is it the case that $ \tilde f $ is an isomorphism?

### Some unnecessary context

At the moment I'm reading Wedhorn's *Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology*, and at some point this question came out.

More precisely, it is claimed in the book that every morphism of ringed spaces of the form $ (\mathbb R^n,\mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n}^\infty) $, where $ \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n}^\infty $ is the sheaf of smoth functions on the euclidean space $ \mathbb R^n $, is automatically a homomorphism of *locally* ringed spaces.

Indeed, let $ (f,f^\flat)\colon (\mathbb R^n,\mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n}^\infty)\to (\mathbb R^m,C_{\mathbb R^m}^\infty) $ be a morphism of ringed spaces and let $ x\in \mathbb R^n $. Then $ (f,f^\flat) $ induces a homomorphism of $ \mathbb R $-algebras
$$
\psi\colon \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^m,f(x)}^\infty/f_x^{-1}(\mathfrak m_x)\to \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n,x}^\infty/\mathfrak m_{x}
$$
where $ f_x\colon \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^m,f(x)}^\infty\to \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n,x}^\infty $ is the canonical map between the stalks at $ x $ and $ \mathfrak m_x $ is the maximal ideal of $ \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n,x}^\infty $. The author claims then that $ \psi $ is surjective, and thus an isomorphism. This shows that (the quotient algebra $ \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^m,f(x)}/f^{-1}(\mathfrak m_x) $ is isomorphic to the field $ \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n,x}/\mathfrak m_x\cong \mathbb R $ and thus) $ f^{-1}(\mathfrak m_x) $ is a maximal ideal. I'm overwhelmed by all this beautiful symbols and I'm not able to see why this should be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to suppose that $f^{-1}(J)\subseteq \ker(q\circ f)$; this is automatically satisfied.

The map $\tilde{f}$ will be injective (check this!). But $\tilde{f}$ may not be surjective. If you assume that $f$ is surjective, then $\tilde{f}$ is surjective, so $\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism.

E.g. take $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R[x]$ to be the inclusion map (which is not surjective) and $J=0$; then $\tilde{f}=f$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But why then the author can conclude that the map $ \psi\colon \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^m,f(x)}^\infty/f^{-1}(\mathfrak m_x)\to \mathscr C_{\mathbb R^n,x}^\infty/m_x $ is surjecive?

Comment: In this case, the map $\psi$ is an injective $\mathbb R$-algebra map into the **field** $C^\infty_{\mathbb R^n,x}/\mathfrak m_x\cong \mathbb R$, so $\psi$ is automatically surjective. (we must have $\psi(1)\neq 0$, so $\psi(a)=a\psi(1)$ can be any real number as we vary $a\in\mathbb R$).

Comment: You mean that if $ \phi\colon A\to B\cong k $ is an injective homomorphism of $ k $-algebras, where $ k $ is a field, then $ \phi $ is necessarily surjective since $ \phi(1_A) = 1_B $, and if $ e\in k $ is the scalar corresponding to a $ b\in B $, then $ \phi(e\cdot 1_A) = e\cdot 1_B = b $?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the main question you asked is more general, and your "unnecessary context" happens to be a very special case.

Comment: Thank you so much then!